# Importing all csv files under a path in seaprate pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a lot of csv files in a folder. For the example say file1.csv to file9.csv. What I want is to import each of these files in separarate dataframes. Importing it in 1 dataframe is no option since all the files have different columns. The code below loops through all the csv files in this filepath and is supposed to import them in different dataframes. However only I don't see 9 dataframes but only 1 called df. Why isn't this working. I thought df.name would do the trick of creating the separate dataframes but it doesn't. Does anyone know what I should change to have this work.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

filepath = r'C:/Source data'

all_files = glob.glob(filepath + "/*.csv")

for filename in all_files:
    name_df = os.path.basename(filename)
    name_df = name_df.replace('.csv','')
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df.name = name_df
```

Comment: make an array of dataframes, currently `df`'s reference is getting modified!

Answer (score 2):

You only see 1 dataframe called df because in every iteration of the loop you overwrite the previous dataframe. What you can do, is have an array of dataframes or a dictionary of dataframes

#### Dictionary Approach

This is useful if you want to access dataframes by name.

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

filepath = r'C:/Source data'

all_files = glob.glob(filepath + "/*.csv")
df_dict = dict()

for filename in all_files:
    name_df = os.path.basename(filename)
    name_df = name_df.replace('.csv','')
    df_dict[name_df] = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

#### List Approach

This is useful if you want to access dataframes by index.

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

filepath = r'C:/Source data'

all_files = glob.glob(filepath + "/*.csv")
df_list = []

for filename in all_files:
    name_df = os.path.basename(filename)
    name_df = name_df.replace('.csv','')
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df_list.append(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Append them to a list of data frames and access by list index e.g. `df_list[0]`:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

filepath = r'C:/Source data'

all_files = glob.glob(filepath + "/*.csv")

df_list = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df_list.append(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `df` object each time you loop. I would suggest using a `dict` of dataframes in this case.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

filepath = r'C:/Source data'

all_files = glob.glob(filepath + "/*.csv")

# create the empty dict to be filled in the loop
dfs = {}

for filename in all_files:
    name_df = os.path.basename(filename)
    name_df = name_df.replace('.csv','')

    # add the df to the dict with the filename as its key
    dfs[name_df] = pd.read_csv(filename)


# then use it like this
print(dfs['file9'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the examples with the dictionary and with the list as well. Both work. Thanks a lot all for your help.